# Save ui elements in activity state

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I am totaly new to java and android. I have the following UI setup:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ...
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        ...>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linLay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

During runtime, some `TextViews` will be added to the `LinearLayout`. I have following problem. The phone filps, the dynamicaly added `TextViews` disapeare. The reason ist that the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method of the activity is called, if you flip your phone.

I setup the following method, to save the instance state (textViews is a member of the Activity class (Vector)):

```java
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {

        super.onSaveInstanceState(state);

        //Save the TextViews
        textViews.removeAllElements();
        LinearLayout layout = getLinearLayout();
        while (layout.getChildCount() > 0)
        {
            View view = layout.getChildAt(0);

            if (view instanceof TextView)
            {
                layout.removeView(view);
                textViews.add((TextView) view);
            }
        }

        state.putSerializable("textViews", textViews);
    }
```

I implemented this cod in the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method to restore the TextViews:

```java
LinearLayout linLay = getLinearLayout();

//Load TextViews
if ((savedInstanceState != null) && (savedInstanceState.getSerializable("textViews") != null))
{
    Serializable serializable = savedInstanceState.getSerializable("textViews");

    if (serializable instanceof Vector)
    {
        textViews= (Vector<TextView>) serializable;
    }
}

if (textViews!= null) {
    for (TextView textView : textViews) {
        linLay.addView(textView);
    }
}
```

This code works for the fliping issue, but it creates a new issue. If I press the home button, I get the following error:

> Parcel: unable to marshal value

I read that the problem is that `Vector<TextView>` is not serializable. But why does fliping the phone does not effect this error? I debugt the app and I am sure, the `state.putSerializable(...)` method is called, if the phone is fliped.

How would you store a `TextView` instead? It is not possible to save a `String` instead of the `TextView`, because the `backgroundResource` of the `TextViews` differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this int solution, but hear me out. TextViews are bunch of text on the screen right? my advice would be when activity recreation will happen dont save TextViews as themselves save text thats in the TextView. and after that use them to draw new ones. this is more logical, more optimized and by using ViewModel it can become more elegant by storing that texts in LiveData of List and observing and reacting in activity. here is documentation for it: [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) and [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)

Comment: Thank you very much. As I mentioned, I already thought about saving the text of the TextView. But what about the style of each TextView. In this case I have to save the `backgroundResource` as well. Ofcourse, I could save the integer, wich represents the `drawable`. But is that the normal way to save each attribute of the UI elements in a seperate Vector? - Thank you very much for the ViewModel documentation. I think that's what I need. I will have look.

Comment: do you have different styles for different view? if you do and you have several types of text views say one represents failure state and other success you could create data class which will be represantion of that text view on high level. and no it really isnt lots of bad things will happen that way, like imagine TextViews need context to be passed in order for them to be created right? if activity will die and new one will be reacreated that Textviews you saved in vector will reference dead activity. which will prevent gc from collecting dead activities reference and it will cause memory leak

Comment: I think I understand. I will check and talk to you after that.

Comment: personally Im not a big fan of inheritance and dont use it unless I really have to. in that case I would have data class say StatusText which will have two property's name and statusBackground. I will have LiveData of List of StatusText in view model. I will have one method which will add StatusText in that list in view model. now I would observe LiveData in my activity and I would react on its change in our case I would add new TextView per new value. when your activity will be recreated it will trigger livedata again and at that point you will have everything you need to add TextViews again.